# Make Explosion Out Of Blocks

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, modifiers, 3d-view, smoke-simulation

I am trying to make an explosion out of legos like you see in the lego movies, I have seen a bunch of tutorials for houdini but none for blender. I tried adding a remesh modifier to a smoke simulation but it did not work.[image: Houdini Lego Explosion]

Comment: use a particle system in which the particles are legos

Comment: Thank you for the response, do you know how I would make a particle system where the legos are particles and also how would I make the legos line up with each other and make the colors change depending on how the smoke and fire are?

Comment: this may help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bpYkNTwK9Pg

Comment: That would totally be awesome if someone could answer this.  what would be really cool is if someone could figure out how to use multiple different types of bricks to build the explosion like in the lego movie, but that probably requires python.  addons anyone?

Comment: I asked this question, and I got a great answer!  The answer with the bounty is the one I think to be the most helpful. here' the link. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/154870/how-do-i-make-more-complex-lego-simulations-in-blender?noredirect=1#comment264586_154870