# How do I make more complex LEGO simulations in Blender?

Tags: smoke-simulation, fluid-simulation, fire

[image]In the lego movie, the fire, water, and smoke is made of lego bricks.  It's not just a simple method of having one type of brick, several different bricks and brick slopes are used to get a really nice effect.  Also, the location of bricks and the types of bricks changes over time.  I have *no* idea how to do this in blender. (I want an animated effect, not a still image.)  is there an addon, or some other way to do this in blender?

(I'm not expecting someone to have an answer that includes smoke, fire, and water, I just want one of them, I figure that any answer someone gives me can be transferred to another)

Comment: I would need a gif or something to see some particulars and examples but my initial suggestion would be to look into swapping out transparencies of different pieces. That's the technique that's used for their facial expressions; I imagine they borrowed from the same bag of tricks to perform other magic.

Comment: how do I include a gif?  I have several images that if played in sequence would make a good gif, but I'm not sure how to include it in the answer.

Comment: I think by editing your initial Ask, you can include gif as a file type. These comments won't take any images.

Comment: @Millard you could use a software that will convert it there are many that can do it and some online ones.

Comment: I apologize for the really low-res gif, I had a hard time reducing it to 2 mb, and now it's less than one, so comment if it's too low.

Comment: @HelloHiHola, as you can see from the gif,(hopefully), swapping out transparency would be way too slow and tedious, I'll need something to hopefully do the work for me :)

Comment: Look into the Remesh Modifier for starters. See if you like that - I'm getting somewhere but it's really requiring some planning so the remesh Octree Depth matches globally from object to object. The studs are giving me trouble. Animate a little Shape Key and watch that Remesh twitch and lurch.

Comment: I've used it before with success, but it only allows the use of one type of brick in the simulation, but if you can see it in the gif, the gif's smoke uses several types of bricks.

Comment: oh, I read your comment more carefully, are you using more than one brick with the remesh modifier?

Comment: Really, my bounty isn't really because of a "lack of attention".  I just think that it's better to award bounties on such long, difficult questions.

Comment: You don't need to justify a bounty. Its okay to want more attention to a problem. I actually watched the movie 2 days ago for the first time and wondered the same thing. Remesh is the first thing to come to mind – displacement modifier maybe for the buttons. I'll look into it a bit deeper

Comment: I've successfully used remesh and dupliverts to make an ocean, but it only allows for one brick to my knowledge.  Also I'm not sure how you would get it to put slope bricks where they need to be.

Comment: Look into "voxel", this is the technique that was used for this film I'm certain.

Comment: Are you talking about voxels like minecraft?  could you send me a link?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bpYkNTwK9Pg
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=83rfinhr2hI


these might help

Comment: I am interested, however if someone else gave an answer that explained how to use more than one kind of brick (especially if they explained how to make it so that the bricks would have slope pieces that followed the curves of the object) I would probably award them the bounty :)

Comment: I'm not sure how you made the pieces have different colors! :)

Comment: @Millard There are sloped pieces, possibly not enough, but you can change the ratio.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

<sup>The [final codes](https://github.com/LeanderSilur/Snippets/tree/master/bpy/lego_bricks) requirements are listed at the end of the post.</sup>

The [tutorial by Ray Mairlot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bpYkNTwK9Pg), which JBlock linked in the comments, is helpful for fluid simulations, or anything with a surface.

I will give insight into a method for volumetrics, specifically smoke, with different pieces. For professional use, you could include [pyopenvdb](https://blenderartists.org/t/openvdb-remesh/1102023) (the [install](https://www.openvdb.org/documentation/doxygen/python.html) is complicated) functionality.

We can access the [`density_grid`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.SmokeDomainSettings.html#bpy.types.SmokeDomainSettings.density_grid) of the smoke with python. From [brickarchitect.com], we gather the dimensions of the smallest brick. (The smallest brick is a third of the heigt in the following image: 3.2mm.)
[image: smallest brick]
<sup>*Click to enlarge*</sup>

#### Distinguishing Slopes with Convolution

We will use **convolution** with the smoke simulations `density_grid` to decide, if we should use a sloped piece or not.

Im going to use the 2 (5) bricks. *brick2* comes in 4 rotation variations, which all have their origin at the bottom left.

[image: smol briggs]
<sup>*Click to enlarge*</sup>

Understanding convolution is crucial, and I recommend [*Understanding Convolutions*](https://colah.github.io/posts/2014-07-Understanding-Convolutions/) and then [*Intuitively Understanding Convolutions*](https://towardsdatascience.com/intuitively-understanding-convolutions-for-deep-learning-1f6f42faee1).

Consider two 2 dimensional 2x2 kernels (red and blue) and a 5x2 image (gray).
To do a single convolution step, overlay a kernel over the image, multiply the overlaying number, add them together, then place them on the image at the position of the top-left square of the kernel.

[image: convolution]

For the red kernel, the convolution of the first pixels, look as follows.

[image: kernel multiplication]

For each different shape [5 (rotated) bricks] we will create a kernel and convolve it with the image. Then, we will compare the kernels and choose the **maximum** value for each pixel. Looking at a single kernel, we compare if its convoluted image has the same value as the *maximum image*. If yes, we can choose the shape and place it at that pixel.

I noticed, that we will need higher resoluted kernels for the slopes and have chosen a 6x9x1 kernel for a sloped piece.

**By changing the weights of each kernel, as well as the *maximum image*, you can easily adjust the ratio of each piece.** In my first render, slopes were quite sparse.

[image: slopes][image: example]
<sup>*Click on the gif for a higher resolution.*</sup>

[image: another angle]

In practice, we can just construct the kernel as a `np.array` and divide it. The more we divide it, the less it will contribute.

```
brick_1.kernel = np.array([[[1, 1, 1]]]) / 8
```

[image: kernel division]

### Steps

Do a smoke simulation.
Import the usual helpful modules for python.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
import numpy as np
from mathutils import Vector
from math import floor, ceil
import scipy.ndimage
```

Get the smoke modifier settings off the domain object.
Get the `density_grid` and calculate the step size. I used a cube, with its bottom-left corner at the world's origin as the domain.

```
depsgraph = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
smoke_obj = bpy.data.objects['domain'].evaluated_get(depsgraph)
smoke_domain_mod = smoke_obj.modifiers[0]
settings = smoke_domain_mod.domain_settings

grid = settings.density_grid
thres = max(grid)/2
res = settings.resolution_max
max_dim = max(smoke_obj.dimensions)
x_step, y_step, z_step = 1/res, 1/res, 1/res
grid = np.array(grid).reshape((res, res, res))
```

If we construct a mesh from this data, and add vertices if the density_grids values are over a certain threshold, then we can visualize the data with vertices.

```
bm = bmesh.new()

for z in range(0, grid.shape[0]):
    for y in range(0, grid.shape[1]):
        for x in range(0, grid.shape[2]):
            if grid[z, y, x] > thres:
                bm.verts.new((x*x_step, y*y_step, z*y_step))

bm.to_mesh(bpy.data.objects['result'].data)
bm.free()
```

[image: grid]
[image: cubes]

After this prototype, for real now. Create a class to sample an object once and instantiate later in another bmesh for the brick types.

In this class

- store a brick bmesh
- store a kernel
- add a method to instantiate the bmesh in another bmesh, we can do this by looping of the vertices and faces in the original mesh and adding them to the new mesh
- add a method to instantiate multiple copies. It takes a grid with True and False values as the input and operates in steps of `X = 0.008 | Y = 0.008 | Z = 0.0096`, the values we read from the original brick image.
- as a bonus I pass along a "color_grid", which we can use to give certain faces a different material index. Currently, faces get assigned to two material slots, so make sure that the target object, which will hold the lego geometry has in fact two materials on slot 0 and 1.

```
class Brick(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.bm = bmesh.new()
        self.bm.from_mesh(bpy.data.objects[name].data)
        self.bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table()
        self.bm.faces.ensure_lookup_table()
        
        self.kernel = None
    
    def instantiate(self, bm_target, at = Vector((0, 0, 0))):
        verts = [bm_target.verts.new(v.co + at) for v in self.bm.verts]
        faces = []
        for f in self.bm.faces:
            face_verts = [verts[v.index] for v in f.verts]
            faces.append(bm_target.faces.new(face_verts))
        return faces
    
    def place(self, bm_target, grid, color_grid):
        sx, sy, sz = 0.008, 0.008, 0.0096
        for z, y_ in enumerate(grid):
            for y, x_ in enumerate(y_):
                for x, value in enumerate(x_):
                    if value:
                        faces = self.instantiate(bm_target, Vector((sx*x, sy*y, sz*z)))
                        mat = 1 if color_grid[z, y, x] > 40 else 0
                        for f in faces:
                            f.material_index = mat

brick_1 = Brick('brick_1')
brick_1.instantiate(bm, Vector((0.2, 0.1, 0)))
```

Since the **evenly spaced** voxels are not the appropriate size for the bricks (which have different x, y, z dimensions), we have to resample the grid with scipys [`ndimage.zoom`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.zoom.html#scipy.ndimage.zoom) function. Note, that the original grid will have stored the values in z, y, x order, which we will work with.

1. Get the dimensions of the smoke_obj in the 3D space and reverse them.
2. Calculate the amount of sample which the smoke simulation has, by using the `smoke_domain`s settings' `resolution_max`.
3. Calculate how many lego samples we require. I used the original bricks dimension and multiplied it with 3. Then we end up with a 6x9

   dimensions = np.flip(np.array(smoke_obj.dimensions))
   samples_smoke = dimensions / np.max(dimensions) * domain_settings.resolution_max
   samples_smoke = np.floor(samples_smoke)
   samples_lego = dimensions / np.array([0.0032, 0.008, 0.008])
   samples_lego = np.floor(samples_lego)

   zoom_factor = samples_lego / samples_smoke * 3

   grid = np.array(grid).reshape(samples_smoke.astype(int))
   grid = scipy.ndimage.zoom(grid, zoom_factor, order=1)

**Example**: If the z, y, x dimension of the domain cube are `0.51, 0.32, 0.32`, and the `resolution_max` is 64, then the voxels are resoluted as `64, 40, 40`. The amount of small (3.2mm x 8mm x 8mm) lego pieces in that area would be `159, 40, 40`, which is stored in `samples_lego`. This results in a `zoom_factor` of `7.45, 3, 3` and a resampled grid the size of `477, 120, 120`. We have to use `ndimage.zoom` with and **order=1** interpolation, because with higher order interpolation, we could receive negative numbers.

I will construct the kernels for these bricks with numpy.
[image: bricks]

```
brick_1.kernel = np.array([[[1, 1, 1]]]) / 8
brick_1.kernel = np.repeat(np.repeat(brick_1.kernel, 9, axis = 0), 3, axis=1)
brick1_grid = scipy.ndimage.convolve(grid, brick_1.kernel)[::9,::3,::3]

brick2a.kernel = np.array([ 
                            [[-6, -6, -1, 0, 1, 1]],
                            [[-6, -5, 0, 1, 1, 1]],
                            [[-5, -3, 0, 1, 1, 1]],
                            [[-4, -1, 0, 1, 1, 1]],
                            [[-3, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]],
                            [[-2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]],
                            [[-1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]],
                            [[1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1]],
                            [[3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
                            ]) / 84
brick2a.kernel = np.repeat(brick2a.kernel, 3, axis=1)
```

The first kernel has dimensions of `9, 3, 3` and the second kernel has dimensions of `9, 3, 6`, since it is a 2 slot brick.

Since we are using a grid, with a higher resolution than our brick size, we can adjust the step size through that grid to get to the discrete steps the size of our smallest brick.

```
brick2a_grid = scipy.ndimage.convolve(grid, brick2a.kernel)[::9,::3,::3]
brick2b_grid = scipy.ndimage.convolve(grid, brick2b.kernel)[::9,::3,::3]
```

To check which if the convolved grids, has the highest value, construct a max grid with a small initial value (`0.065`). Where there is no smoke, the other grids will have values of `0`. When comparing them to our small number in each cell of the `max_grid`, the max grid will be larger. This results in no bricks filling those spots. No smoke -> no bricks.
For each brick, we check if it has larger values in its convoluted grid.

```
max_grid = np.ones(grid.shape, dtype=np.float)[::9,::3,::3] * 0.065

max_grid = np.maximum(max_grid, brick1_grid)
max_grid = np.maximum(max_grid, brick2a_grid)
```

If we compare a grid of a brick with the `max_grid` (`brick1_grid == max_grid`), then we get a binary array, which holds `True` for the positions, where we have to place the brick kind. For that, I use the place function which we wrote earlier.

```
bm = bmesh.new()
brick_1.place(bm, brick1_grid == max_grid, density_grid)
brick2a.place(bm, brick2a_grid == max_grid, density_grid)
...
```

For the rotated brick2's (brick2b, brick2c, brick2d), we can simply switch flip the kernel of brick2a and/or swap its axes.

#### Download the script here

The final code ([github: smoke_to_lego.py](https://github.com/LeanderSilur/Snippets/tree/master/bpy/lego_bricks)) assumes

- a baked smoke domain object named 'domain'
- the brick objects *brick_1, brick_2a, brick_2b, brick_2c, brick_2d*
- a target mesh object named *result*
- an installed scipy module. You can install [a module](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/41258/30849) for your local python distribution, but I choose the unclean, easy way and simply did a pip install (`python -m pip install scipy`) in Blender 2.8 python executable directory.

[image]

After downloading the file, bake the smoke simulation. Then execute the script on a frame with smoke. The script takes approx 5-20s in the given resolution during which Blender is unresponsive.

To render all of the frames, simply call the wrapped operation while looping through all frames.

```
# call the method to generate the geometry for this current frame
if True:
    generate_lego_geometry()

# loop through all the frame to render all frames
# this will be slow and won't show visual feedback
if False:
    scn = bpy.context.scene
    for frame in range(scn.frame_start, scn.frame_end + 1):
        scn.frame_set(frame)
        generate_lego_geometry()
        scn.render.filepath = "//output/" + str(frame).zfill(4) + ".png"
        bpy.ops.render.render(animation=False, write_still=True)
```

I won't update the script in the .blend. The github link is up to date.

Comment: will I have to run the script for every frame or will it run for an animation?

Comment: how did you do the materials?  did you just have a different material on each sample brick?

Comment: Yes, correct, youd would have to run the script on every frame. I will extend the script to automate that, which is what I used to render the preview. (I can do that later probably). If you look in the place method for the bricks, you will see how a material index is assigned for every brick. This requires two materials on the target object *result*. I just realized, that this would be easier to process with vertex colors. I will try to update that asap as well. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Thank _you_ for the script!  i look forward to future updates!

Comment: Having looked at this problem myself, I'm loving this solution, it's a real education for me. If extended with code to replace the smoke density grid with your own inside/outside-of-a- _mesh_  grid (with appropriate XYZ increments), you could lego-ize or otherwise irregularly voxelize any mesh. I think that would be quite a popular add-on, out there.

Comment: PS.. If I'm reading right, you're convolving the entire grid, and _then_ extracting the stepped results. Does SciPy/anything provide a way of stepping the convoulution itself?

Comment: @Robin If you want to use your own inside/outside of a mesh you should use pyopenvdb, which will provide many functions by it's own. [The better remesher here](https://blenderartists.org/t/openvdb-remesh/1102023) is an example, but as you can see from the threads posts compiling openvdb for your system sounds tedious. You're right, in theory there are many convoluted squares which aren't necessary. Since we only use a single position of all summed values, you probably wouldn't even need convolution but some multiplication and a reduce operation, but convolution is fast and I'm lazy.

Answer (score 2):

There is also an addon made specifically for this in Blender; may be worth looking into as it streamlines the whole process: https://blendermarket.com/products/bricker

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use geometry node - position to determine node set responsible for coloring legos in effect.
You can also create separate legos, create geometry and add particle system that will emit lego bricks at this geometry(faces/verts). If you choose to emit random lego cube from set of cubes you made earlier, choose their lifetime very short, and emit them often you should get nice effect :) Try looking for addon for generating effect geometry. Im not sure if shape keys would work in this case.[image: lego]
So I created geometry from landscape addon I set large emmit number. Lifetime 1. The problem is that despite I can control water movement on the time of creation of landscape by just changing its offset value, I cannot animate it after :(
Photo above shows slopes. If you create grid-like mesh steps can be exactly 1 lego block (tested). You will than need to use grid mesh with geometry boolean modifier.

Update:
You can actually use shape keys, but not in direct meaning of this. You create multiple meshes from landscape modifier, that differ a bit using offset x or y. This will make them look like next frames of water. Then make shape keys on those objects and then you can hit space "transfer shape keys" into mesh that creates particle simulation. And make transition between tham making key frames on their proportion.

Comment: it's a good idea, so i upvoted it, but It wouldn't work for slopes, as the particle system doesn't know where to put slopes and where not to.

Comment: (there is some slopes in the the gif i showed, but they are the 1x1 brick types, and this simulation isn't quite as detailed as for instance, the ocean scene in lego movie)